# Ошибка Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in E:\OSPanel\domains\yeticave.ru\index.php on line 32

Tags: php, html

Вот код, не пойму где не закрыл тег.

```
<?php if ($is_auth == true) {
            <div class="user-menu__image" >
                <img src=$user_avatar width="40" height="40" alt="Пользователь">
            </div>
            <div class="user-menu__logged">
                <p>@user_name</p>
            </div>
        }
        else {
            <ul class="user-menu__list">
                <li class="user-menu__item">
                    <a href = "#">Регистрация</a>
                </li>
                <li class="user-menu__item">
                    <a href = "#">Вход</a>
                </li>
            </ul> }
            ?>
```

Comment: А на каком основании Вы выводите html код внутри тегов `<?php` так нельзя делать! У вас везде тег не закрыт получается)

Comment: echo '<div>'; ///

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тут вариантов несколько.. либо закрывать php теги:

```
<?php if ($is_auth == true) { ?>
    <div class="user-menu__image" >
        <img src="<?=$user_avatar?>" width="40" height="40" alt="Пользователь">
    </div>
    <div class="user-menu__logged">
        <p>@user_name</p>
    </div> <?php
}
else { ?>
    <ul class="user-menu__list">
        <li class="user-menu__item">
            <a href = "#">Регистрация</a>
        </li>
        <li class="user-menu__item">
            <a href = "#">Вход</a>
        </li>
    </ul> <?php 
} ?>
```

либо через echo:

```
<?php if ($is_auth == true) { 
   echo "<div class='user-menu__image' >
             <img src='".$user_avatar."' width='40' height='40' alt='Пользователь'>
         </div>
         <div class='user-menu__logged'>
             <p>@user_name</p>
         </div>";
    }
    else {
    echo "<ul class='user-menu__list'>
              <li class='user-menu__item'>
                  <a href='#'>Регистрация</a>
              </li>
              <li class='user-menu__item'>
                  <a href='#'>Вход</a>
              </li>
          </ul>";
    }
```